# Where clause on json data in Sql Server 2016

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-server-2016, json-query, sql-server-json

I have a nvarchar(1000) field in my table and I am storing JSON data in that column.

eg :

```
 CONTENT_RULE_ID    CONTENT_RULE
 1                  {"EntityType":"Inquiry", "Values":[1,2]}
 2                  {"EntityType":"Inquiry", "Values":[1,3]}
 3                  {"EntityType":"Inquiry", "Values":[2,4]}
 4                  {"EntityType":"Inquiry", "Values":[5,6,1]}
 6                  {"EntityType":"Inquiry", "Values":[8,1]}
 8                  {"EntityType":"Inquiry", "Values":[10,12,11]}
```

from this how can I get all the CONTENT_RULE_ID which is having inquiry id 1 using JSON_QUERY in sql server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Harisyam, could you please try following query

```
declare @val int = 1

;with cte as (
    select *
    from CONTENT_RULES
    cross apply openjson (CONTENT_RULE, '$')
), list as (
    select 
    CONTENT_RULE_ID, replace(replace([value],'[',''),']','') as [value]
    from cte 
    where CONTENT_RULE_ID in (
    select CONTENT_RULE_ID
    from cte 
    where [key] = 'EntityType' and [value] = 'Inquiry'
    ) 
    and [key] = 'Values'
)
select 
CONTENT_RULE_ID, s.value
from list
cross apply string_split([value],',') s
where s.value = @val
```

I used SQL [string_split function](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/split-string-function-in-sqlserver-2016.aspx) to get inquiry values one by one

output is

[image]

A second query can be following one

```
select
    CONTENT_RULE_ID
from CONTENT_RULES
cross apply openjson (CONTENT_RULE, '$')
where replace(replace(value,'[',','),']',',') like '%,1,%'
```

And maybe the most complete SQL query which requires OpenJSON support is as follows

```
select
    content_rule_id,
    [value]
from Content as c
cross apply openjson(c.CONTENT_RULE, '$') with (
    EntityType nvarchar(100),
    [Values] nvarchar(max) as json
) as e
cross apply openjson([Values], '$') as v
```

Comment: Hi @Erapler,

Thanks for your help. Your solution worked as expected.
But is there any easy way to do this using any inbuilt function, similar to IN statement in normal sql query

Comment: And what about your SQL Server version? Is it supporting OpenJSON ? I guess so since you seemed to test it

Comment: Yes it supports OpenJSON since I am using SQL Server 2016

Comment: I added another one into the answer

Comment: This is simple and working. I found another way without string replace function

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT c.*
FROM CONTENT_RULES AS c
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(JSON_QUERY(content_rule, '$')) AS x 
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(x.[Value], '$') AS y
where x.[key]='Values' and y.[value]=1
```

Answer (score 1):

My case is similar but instead of an integer array, mine is an array of complex type. Here is my code based on [David Browne's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54014934/823247)

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName AS T
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM OPENJSON(T.JsonColumn, '$.Details')
    WITH
    (
        OrderNumber VARCHAR(200) '$.OrderNumber',
        Quantity INT '$.Quantity'
    )
    WHERE OrderNumber = '1234567'
);
```

In your case:

```
SELECT C.*
FROM CONTENT_RULES AS C
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM OPENJSON(C.CONTENT_RULE, '$.Values')
    WHERE value = 1
);
```

Answer (score 0):

sql server 2016 can open JSON.

Try this:

```
SELECT c.content_rule_ID, y.[key], y.[value]
  FROM content_rules AS c
  CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(JSON_QUERY(content_rule, '$.content_rule')) AS x
  CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(x.[Values], '$') AS y
  where y.[value] = 1
    and x.[EntityType] = 'Inquiry';
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This solution is not working. But from your answer, I got the idea to do this.

Comment: SELECT c.*
FROM CONTENT_RULES AS c
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(JSON_QUERY(content_rule, '$')) AS x 
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(x.[Value], '$') AS y
where x.[key]='Values' and y.[value]=1

Comment: Also added as an answer