# How to do Where clause on simple Json Array in SQL Server 2017?

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-server-2017

Say I have a column in my database called `attributes` which has this value as an example:

```
  {"pages":["Page1"]}
```

How can I do a where clause so I can filter down rows that have "Page1" in it.

```
  select JSON_QUERY(Attributes, '$.pages') 
  from Table
  where JSON_QUERY(Attributes, '$.pages') in ('Page1')
```

**Edit:**

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) it seems like this might work though it seems so complicated for what it is doing.

```
  select count(*)
  from T c
  cross apply Openjson(c.Attributes)
              with (pages nvarchar(max) '$.pages' as json) 
  outer apply openjson(pages) 
              with ([page] nvarchar(100) '$')
  where [page] = 'Page1'
```

Comment: instead of in, have you tried using like ? I I think it gives the instances where we have Page 1 references (without even using Json_query), also with Json_query are you trying to extract the value there or the JSON format in the select list ?

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
use tempdb
create table T(id int, Attributes nvarchar(max))

insert into T(id,Attributes) values (1, '{"pages":["Page1"]}')
insert into T(id,Attributes) values (2, '{"pages":["Page3","Page4"]}')
insert into T(id,Attributes) values (3, '{"pages":["Page3","Page1"]}')

select *
from T
where exists
( 
  select * 
  from openjson(T.Attributes,'$.pages') 
  where value = 'Page1'
)
```

returns

```
id          Attributes
----------- ---------------------------
1           {"pages":["Page1"]}
3           {"pages":["Page3","Page1"]}

(2 rows affected)
```

Comment: ok, I will try that. I also came up with above from examples I found on the MS docs, though I think your seems simpler.